# How can create one UITableview to multiple segue in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Using storyboard, I create a UITableview with seven rows and also create seven `UIViewController`s for each row. I want to navigate to the particular UIViewController when the particular row is selected. How do I navigate the UIViewController using the Segue method?

I tried it many times, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect seven segues from your `UITableViewController` to your seven `UIViewController`. Each `segue` sets a unique `identifier`. Then in the `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can use `perfromSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method to fire the segue.

Comment: ok but only one segue can be create from UITableviewcontroller to UIviewcontroller remaining are cannot created in storyboard

Comment: Don't you have seven UIviewcontrollers created in storyboard?

Comment: Than why can't you create seven segues from UITableviewcontroller to them?

Comment: Only one segue can create from UITableview to one UIViewcontroller another segue from UITableview to UIviewcontroller cannot create.

Comment: @Surendhar Try to link from the UITableViewController but not from the cell nor the tableView. select the UITableViewController through clicking the status bar of your UITableViewController, then link it to the UIViewcontroller. Then repeat seven times. good luck!